# Caps lock indicator in Mint 18

Tags: keyboard, linux-mint

How can I do to enable the next caps/num lock indicator in Mint 18?

[image: caps lock symbol in Mint 18]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!!! At Accessibility settings:
[image: CapsLock Indicator Mint 18.1]